# Creating bulk posts with Youtube videos

Tags: php, posts, customization, youtube, bulk

I'm a bit new to Wordpress and I'm a bit lost reading all sort of docs about creating bulk posts using PHP. I've wrote a small code that using Youtube API v3 to get all the videos from a Youtube channel and I want to create post in wordpress using that loop and data.

My code is below if anyone needs it for any sort of usage and I will appriciate any help and explenation about how to create mass post using PHP and how to execute the code using wordpress.

```
    <?php

$var = file_get_contents("test.txt"); // list of category IDs
$var = explode("\n", $var);

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "xxxxx";
$password = "xxxxx";
$dbname = "xxxxx";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

function updateYoutube( $videocode ){
    global $conn;

    $run = $conn->query("SELECT `ID` FROM `youtubetable` WHERE `ID` = '$videocode'");

    if ($run->num_rows > 0)
        return false;
    else
    {
        if ($conn->query("INSERT INTO youtubetable (`ID`) VALUES ('$videocode')") === TRUE)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}

foreach($var as $value)
{
    $value = file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=contentDetails&id=$value&key={KEY}");
    $value = json_decode($value);
    $value = $value->items;

    foreach( $value as $id) {
        $playlist = $id->contentDetails->relatedPlaylists->uploads;

        if(empty($playlist))
            continue;

        $playlist = file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&playlistId=$playlist&key={KEY}&maxResults=50");
        $playlist = json_decode($playlist);
        $playlist = $playlist->items;

        foreach( $playlist as $video) {
            $videocode = $video->snippet->resourceId->videoId;

        updateYoutube( $videocode );

        }
    }

}

$conn->close();                                                                                                                                                                                         

?>
```

Update:

I'm trying to create post for every new $videocode (in a loop) and insert the $videocode to a custom post field I have: "video_url" and a some static/dynamic "post_title"

Thanks in advance

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Create a bunch of posts, one YouTube video per post?

Comment: I've updated my goals: "I'm trying to create post for every new $videocode (in a loop) and insert the $videocode to a custom post field I have: "video_url" and a some static/dynamic "post_title""

Comment: Could you not just store all these as a post of type `youtube`? `wp_insert_post` is your friend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have your `updateYoutube()` function. Edit it to [insert a new post](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post). Very generally:

```
function updateYoutube( $videocode ){
    global $conn;

    $run = $conn->query("SELECT `ID` FROM `youtubetable` WHERE `ID` = '$videocode'");

    if ($run->num_rows > 0)
        return false;
    else
    {
        if ($conn->query("INSERT INTO youtubetable (`ID`) VALUES ('$videocode')") === TRUE) {
          // #################################
          // NOTE: The following 99% cribbed from the wp_insert_post() entry in the Codex
          // Create post object
          $my_post = array(
            'post_title'    => 'My post',
            'post_content'  => $videocode,
            'post_status'   => 'publish',
            'post_author'   => 1,
            'post_category' => array(8,39) // Obviously illustrative only
          );

          // Insert the post into the database
          wp_insert_post( $my_post );
          // ##################################
          return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

The [auto-embedding system](https://codex.wordpress.org/Embeds) should, I believe, take care of the rest, though I have not tested it.

Comment: First of all, thank you. I will set the function in the functions.php page aight? Can I access this function only from pages in the WordPress itself? If I have a custom field like I mentioned above, should I just use this code: $my_post = array(
            'post_title'    => 'My post',
            'video_url'     => $videocode,
            'post_status'   => 'publish',
            'post_author'   => 1,
            'post_category' => array(8,39)